# Get the current value of an attribute, not the original

Tags: jquery

How can I get jQuery to see the current value on a page after I have changed it? I have a set of radio buttons that control the display of the page. In the background I set a flag based on that. For example I have:

```
<span id="group" data-group="1"></span>
```

After selecting a radio button this changes to:

```
<span id="group" data-group="2"></span>
```

I also have a page refresh running which looks at these flags and reloads the page accordingly. Except it doesn't.

If the page had `Group=1` when it first loaded, and I change it to `Group=2`, I want it to reload using `Group=2`. But it doesn't, it still reloads using `Group=1`. I am looking for the flag using:

```
group = $('#group').data('group');
```

Is there a way to get it to pick up the current value, not the original value?

---UPDATE

OK, I have added the following if it helps?

https://jsfiddle.net/IGGt/qk6n8z9h/6/

It doesn't quite work as for some reason it wont read the PHP, but hopefully gives you a pretty good idea of what I am doing.

But basically after x seconds it reloads the page using the following string:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function() { document.location.href="index.php?group="+group }, timer);
```

I then have a piece at the top of the page that does:

```
<?php
$group = ((ISSET ($_GET['group'])) ? $_GET['group'] : 1 );
```

The problem is, that if the page was loaded using `group == 2`, and I then change it to `group=1`, it reloads, using `group=2`.

Comment: What you have should work (and does: http://jsfiddle.net/fzoa5t8h/). Is there multiple elements with the `group` id? Also you state the page is being refreshed - is the value being reset too?

Comment: when are you `group = $('#group').data('group');` executing this? after value change or before?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
       $('#group').on('change', function(){
         group = $(this).data('group');
        });
    </script>
```

> if you have set of radio buttons with id ('#group') then this code can
>   be helpful to find out current value.

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively keeping page "state" within the html of the page, which can make things quite complex (eg where do you detect changes, which is the error you are seeing)

If you have a page refresh going on the values will all reset to their values as written in your code. To persist values over a refresh, you can use a variety of methods like URL queries, sessionstorage (sounds most appropriate for this), cookies, etc.

For showing hiding areas of the page based on radio buttons, instead of updating the `data-group` property and then reading it in, update a variable within your js.

Now if you create a function to set the page state based on the value in this variable, you can separate your 'set the variable' and 'make the page look like the variable' methods.

Simply call the 'page state' method at page load based on your persisted value (or a default, 1), and every time after the state variable has changed.

Sorry it's not a demonstration code, as Liam said we need a set of your current code, but as a methodology it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your default value for the group-data is 1 for the page load and the page is loading for this value i.e 1, next you are changing group-data to 2 now you want to load the page with group-data value 2 not with your default value i.e 1.
If this is the case you can do achieve page load for group-data value 2 in 2 ways:
1. Use query string approach: When you are trying to load the page load with a query string at URL for the selected group data, capture this query string value in your document.ready function do the necessary functionality you want to do for group-data selected.
2. Second approach is save your group-data in local-storage then you can retrieve your data during document.ready then do the stuff what you want to do for selected group-data.